# How can I make a method to acces a data.table in a structure?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have this:

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1:10, y = 1:2)
s <- structure(list(dt = dt), class = 'dt_test')
```

I want to define a [ function for objects of class dt_test that will pass on its arguments to dt. So for example I want to be able to do things like

```
s[, sum(x), by = y]
s[, z := x + y]
```

where the [ is applied to dt. How can I make this happen?

Comment: This looks overly complicated to me. Are you aware that `s$dt[, sum(x), by = y]` will give you the result?

Comment: Yes, but I will be doing many manipulations of objects like this and it would be very convenient if I didn't have to type $dt every time.

Comment: All right, just checking :) Does Stefan Fs answer work for you? And would `s` contain only one df or multiple?

Comment: Works just fine, although 22 minutes later I realized that doing `s <- s[y == 2]` vs. `s$dt <- st$dt[y==2]` leads to a very unpleasant surprise. Probably best to avoid this idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, i'm not sure it should be done though. Defining a method for `[` that sends its arguments down to the data.table is pretty straight forward:

```
`[.dt_test` <- function(x, ...){
  x[[1]][...]
}

s[, sum(x), by = y]
```

You would have to do something similar for all generics that you want supported, for example you will probably also want to define `[[`.

I would rather recommend referring to the data.table inside the list directly, like Majo suggested in his comment to your question. That way your it's easier to understand whats really happening in your code to someone else who might be reading it (e.g. future you).

Comment: Gonna take you up on the not doing this idea. These are too easy to confuse and lead to wildly different places: `s <- s[y == 2]` vs. `s$dt <- st$dt[y==2]`

Comment: Maybe you can tweak the function a bit to deal with this issue, but it might become awkward when dealing with set-by-reference things in data.table

Comment: Maybe I could but then what other issues are gonna pop up later? I feel like it's better to give up some amount of convenience for the peace of mind. I didn't think of that when I asked the question.

Comment: Do you really need the structures? Maybe use a data.table with additional attributes (`?attr`) might be enough? (but be aware that custom attributes get lost at most modification operations)